# Update: How to compare values in 3 consecutive rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a solution which would compare values in 3 consecutive rows of data and update column if condition is true.

```
import pandas as pd aapl = pd.read_csv(....)
aapl['3lows'] = False
aapl.head(10)
```

and the output is the table where for each row there are columns with

```
Row number/ Date / Open / High / Low / Close / Adj Close / Volume / 3lows
0 / 2006-01-03 / 10.340000 / 10.678572 / 10.321428 / 10.678572 / 9.572629 / 201808600 / False
```

Now I want to run some "script" to update column 3lows to true if value in column Low from row that is being updated e.g. 100 is lower than from row 99, and from 99 lower than from 98 and from 98 lower than 97.

Comment: Hi @Radovan. Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is designed to help you solve problems, rather than solve them completely for you. Could you post some code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: Also, including a list of sample input and expected output is really helpful for those answering your question. Addressing your question, I believe shifting columns is probably the way you want to go, but it's hard to tell without example input/output.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Let use something like this:

```
#where is is the s = appl['Low']; let's make up some data
s = pd.Series([100,99,98,97,99,100,99,95,94,93,92,100,95])

s.diff().rolling(3).max().lt(0)
```

Returns:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
dtype: bool
```

Details:

```
s
```

Output:

```
0     100
1      99
2      98
3      97
4      99
5     100
6      99
7      95
8      94
9      93
10     92
11    100
12     95
dtype: int64
```

Compare each value to previous using `diff`:

```
s.diff()
```

Output:

```
0     NaN
1    -1.0
2    -1.0
3    -1.0
4     2.0
5     1.0
6    -1.0
7    -4.0
8    -1.0
9    -1.0
10   -1.0
11    8.0
12   -5.0
dtype: float64
```

Now, let's look at a rolling windows of 3 values if the max is less than zero then you have three declines in a value:

```
s.diff().rolling(3).max().lt(0)
```

Output:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
12    False
dtype: bool
```

Now, let's compare our result to the original data:

```
print(pd.concat([s,s.diff().rolling(3).max().lt(0)], axis=1))

      0      1
0   100  False
1    99  False
2    98  False
3    97   True
4    99  False
5   100  False
6    99  False
7    95  False
8    94   True
9    93   True
10   92   True
11  100  False
12   95  False
```